I cant update and image with put method on Laravel inertiajs
I have three files here: Edit.vue, FormComponent, and a resource method that allows only PUT and PATCH. When I submit without an image, the update method works, but when I attach an image in the form, it results in an error stating, 'input retrieve failed,' with a message like 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null.' The update query looks like this: UPDATE categories SET name = ?, description = ?, category_slug = ?, categories.updated_at = '2024-06-21 20:59:40' WHERE id = 1.
If someone can help me with Inertia.js and Vue, I would greatly appreciate it.
This is the Edit.vue code.
<template>
  <Head title="Edit Category" />
  <DefaultLayouts>
    <div class="flex flex-row">
      <div class="w-1/2 p-4">
        <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold mb-4">Edit Category</h2>
        <div v-if="flashMessage" class="text-red-900 p-4">
          {{ flashMessage }}
        </div>
        <CategoryForm
          :singlecategory="singlecategory"
          :submitLabel="'Update'"
          @submit="handleSubmit"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </DefaultLayouts>
</template>

<script setup>
import DefaultLayouts from "../Layouts/DefaultLayouts.vue";
import CategoryForm from "../Components/CategoryForm.vue";
import { usePage, useForm, Head } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { computed } from "vue";
const page = usePage();
//const singlecategory = page.props.singlecategory;
const flashMessage = computed(() => page.props.flash.message);
const props = defineProps({
  singlecategory: Object,
});
const handleSubmit = (form) => {
  form.put(route("categories.update", props.singlecategory.id), {
    forceFormData: true,
    onSuccess: () => form.reset(),
  });
};
</script>


This is the CategoryForm.vue code.
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import TextInput from "../Components/TextInput.vue";
import InputError from "../Components/InputError.vue";
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  categories: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({}),
  },
  singlecategory: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({}),
  },
  submitLabel: {
    type: String,
    default: "Submit",
  },
});

const emits = defineEmits(["submit"]);

const form = useForm({
  name: props.singlecategory.name || "",
  description: props.singlecategory.description || "",
  category_image: props.singlecategory.category_image || "",
  category_slug: props.singlecategory.category_slug || "",
});

const handleSubmit = () => {
  emits("submit", form);
};

watch(
  () => form.name,
  (newVal) => {
    form.category_slug = newVal.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
  }
);
</script>

<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <div>
      <label for="name" class="block font-medium">Category Name</label>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        id="name"
        v-model="form.name"
        class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-blue-300 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
        required
      />
      <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="description" class="block font-medium">Description</label>
      <textarea
        id="description"
        name="description"
        v-model="form.description"
        class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-blue-300 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
      ></textarea>
      <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.description" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="category_slug" class="block font-medium">Category Slug</label>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        id="category_slug"
        v-model="form.category_slug"
        class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-blue-300 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
        required
      />
      <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.category_slug" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="categoryImage" class="block font-medium">Category Image</label>
      <input
        class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-blue-300 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        @input="form.category_image = $event.target.files[0]"
      />
      <progress v-if="form.progress" :value="form.progress.percentage" max="100">
        {{ form.progress.percentage }}%
      </progress>
      <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.category_image" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button
        class="inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 mt-4 sm:mt-6 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg focus:ring-4 focus:ring-primary-200 dark:focus:ring-primary-900 hover:bg-primary-800"
        :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }"
        :disabled="form.processing"
      >
        {{ submitLabel }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>


This is my resource controller update block.
   public function update(Request $request, $category)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        $categoryupdate = Category::findOrFail($category);

        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('categories')->ignore($categoryupdate->id)],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'string'],
            'category_image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'category_slug' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('categories')->ignore($categoryupdate->id)],
        ]);

        
        $categoryupdate->name = $request->name;
        $categoryupdate->description = $request->description;
        $categoryupdate->category_slug = Str::limit($request->category_slug, 40);


        if ($request->hasFile('category_image')) {
            // Delete old image if exists
            if ($categoryupdate->category_image) {


                Storage::delete('public/images/category/' . $categoryupdate->category_image);
            }

            $file_name = time() . '.' . $request->category_image->extension();
            request()->category_image->move(public_path('images/category'), $file_name);
            $categoryupdate->category_image = $file_name;
        }

        if ($categoryupdate->save()) {
            $request->session()->flash('message', 'Category updated successfully.');
            return to_route('categories.index');
        }
    }

I want to upload an image and update replace the image with old one.
